# Echoing PHP TAG showing blank output HTML

Tags: php

I am testing this on windows 7 xammp 1.8.1 php 5.4.7

I am trying to show dynamic php codes in html as example

my code is

```
<?php
$output="<?php echo $ti ?>";
echo $output;
 ?>
```

but output html is blank! i am not sure if its a bug, can some help me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the characters

This can be done by adding the entire line you want to output in an htmlentities function call, like:

```
 $output = htmlentities("<?php echo \$ti ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run this, this DOES produce an output, which is a blank page, because the output is:

```
<?php echo  ?>
```

To a browser which renders html, it will look like an open tag with nothing in value.

Run your script and view the page source...

Comment: thanks. on page source its showing <?php echo $ti ?> as ouput but i need to this on page itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes

i.e.

change

```
    <?php
     $output="<?php echo $ti ?>";
     echo $output;
     ?>
```

to

```
      <?php
     $output='<?php echo $ti ?>';
     echo $output;
     ?>
```

Comment: doh i forgot to add $output =  htmlentities('<?php echo $ti ?>');
     echo $output;

Answer (score 0):

Just change your double quotes to single quotes:

```
<?php
$output='<?php echo $ti ?>';
echo $output;
 ?>
```

Example: http://ideone.com/bUJAxb

Comment: thanks but that's giving same blank output. and on eaxmple link "" is also working. is it bug then?

Comment: @Sumanta then maybe you have some strange php setup. Depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve you can just close the tag and use plain html instead. e.g. http://ideone.com/JpWbQ8

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you have to change. First, if you use double quotes PHP will evaluate variables in it, so your output will be `<?php echo ?>`:

```
$output='<?php echo $ti ?>';
```

Now the output will be `<?php echo $ti ?>`.

Next, the browser will interpret this as HTML and since it is only a single tag it will display nothing. You need to run this through `htmlentities()`:

```
echo htmlentities($output);
```

This will output `&lt;? echo $ti ?;gt;` which will be displayed by the browser in the way you intend it.